# How to make jQuery .map only add filled inputs to array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So here is my jQuery:

```
var optionsArray = $(".optionInput").map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

Currently it gets all of the inputs with the class .optionInput and puts the data into an array, but it also stores blank inputs too. With my site I don't need all the inputs to be filled, but I don't want the function to collect any data from the blank fields. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> If the function returns null or undefined, no element will be inserted

source: [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/map/)

```
var optionsArray = $(".optionInput").map(function() {
    return this.value || null;
}).get();
```

Jsfiddle [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dh8r59s5/)

Comment: Cool! Never knew of this

Comment: Very nice! Didn't know about it too.

Comment: Just be aware that most other implementations of `map`-like functionality _don't_ have this special feature.